# Could we have $P_X(X=x_i)=Pr(\{s_j\in S: X(s_j)=x_i\})$, but $\{s_j\in S: X(s_j)=x_i\}$ is not an element of the original sigma algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

On Casella and Berger Statistical Inference (2nd edition), equation (1.4.1) defines induced probability $P_X(X=x_i)=P({s_j\in S: X(s_j)=x_i})$ for random variable $X$ that is a mapping from $S={s_1,...,s_n}$ to $\mathcal{X}={x_1,...,x_m}$. But there seems to be some gap in this definition.

For example $S=\{A,B,C\}$, and the original sigma algebra $\mathbb{B}=\{\{A\},\{B,C\},\emptyset,S\}$, and the original probability function $P(\cdot)$ is a mapping from $\mathbb{B}$ to [0,1]. Suppose the random variable is $X(A)=1$, $X(B)=1$ and $X(C)=2$ so that the new sample space $\mathscr{X}=\{1,2\}$. However, $P_X(X=1)=P(\{A,B\})$, while $P(\{A,B\})$ is undefined as $\{A,B\}$ is not an element of the original sigma algebra.

What's wrong with this example?  What are the more general restrictions that induced probability should satisfy to eliminate this problem?

Comment: It seems to me that your random variables $X$ is not measurable for the original sigma algebra.

Comment: @Youem Thanks! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a random variable is a measurable function on a probability space. The function $X$ in your example is not measurable (thus it is not a random variable): you showed it, by providing a set $X^{-1}(C)\notin \mathbb{B}$ for some $C \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. Just one question, what is $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$? Is it the sigma algebra formed by subsets of the real line? If yes, I have another question, suppose I fix my example by setting $\mathbb{B}$ as the power set of $S$. As the range of $X$ is only $\mathscr{X}=\{1,2\}$, why do we equip it with $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ instead of the the power set of $\mathscr{X}$? For any random variables, do we always use $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @ExcitedSnail you're welcome. That $\sigma$-algebra is called the Borel $\sigma$-algebra; canonically defined as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets in $\mathbb{R}$. The fact that $X$ takes only the values $1$ and $2$ is not of importance in this context. What is important is that $X:S \to \mathbb{R}$. The definition of measurable function is: $X$ maps $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and for any $C \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$, we have $X^{-1}(C)\in \mathbb{B}$. You provided the example of $X^{-1}(\{1\})$ not being in $\mathbb{B}$, proving non-measurability.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very clear. Indeed $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ could adapt any $\mathcal{X}$. In my fixed example, on the one hand $\{1\}$ is an element in $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$, as it could be the result of countable intersection of open set $(1-1/n,1+1/n)$. On the other hand, for objects that are irrelevant to the range of $X$, such as interval $(0,0.5)$ in my example, their counterpart in the original sigma algebra will be the empty set, right?

Comment: Yes, $\{1\}=\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(1-1/n,1+1/n)$, and it belongs to $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ because [countable intersections of measurable sets belong to $\sigma$-algebras](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sigma-Algebra_Closed_under_Countable_Intersection). Also, $X^{-1}((0,0.5))=\{s\in S:X(s)\in (0,0.5)\}=\emptyset$. @ExcitedSnail